# A frog in a pond with an infinite number of lily pads: equilibrium distribution.

Tags: probability, markov-chains

For my homework, I have the following problem:
A frog inhabits a pond with an infinite number of lily pads, numbered 1,2,3,... She hops from pad to pad in the following manner: if she happens to be on pad $i$ at given time, she hops to one of the pads (1,2, ..., $i$, $i+1$) with equal probability.

I have to find the equilibrium distribution corresponding to this markov chain. My book gives the following hint: Just guess $\pi_1$ and find $\pi_i$ recursively. Proof with induction.

I'm having difficulties 'guessing' $\pi_1$, so it would be nice if anyone could help me with that.

Comment: "She hops from pad to pad". How does the hop from $i$ to $i$ looks like?

Comment: Trying this empirically, taking $\pi_1=(1,0,0,0,0,\ldots)$ and then running the Markov Chain $100$ times on the first $100$ lily pads was probably excessive but pointed to a stable distribution and by dividing one term by the next, the distribution was not difficult to spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $i^\text{th}$ pad can be reached from pads indexed $i-1,i,i+1,...$ with probabilities $\frac1i,\frac1{i+1},\frac1{i+2},...$ respectively. Thus steady state probability of $i^\text{th}$ lily pad,$$p_i=\sum_{k=i-1}^\infty\frac{p_k}{k+1};i\ge1,p_0=0$$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k=1$. So $p_i=\frac{p_{i-1}}i+p_{i+1}$, giving us$$p_{n}=p_{n-1}-\frac{p_{n-2}}{n-1},n\ge2$$which gives$$p_2=p_1,p_3=p_1/2,p_4=p_1/6,p_5=p_1/24,p_6=p_1/120,...$$ so it seems the general solution is $p_n=p_1/(n-1)!,n\ge1,$ which can be verified to solve the recurrence.$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty p_i=1\implies p_1\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac1{(n-1)!}=p_1e=1$$giving $p_1=1/e$ and $p_n=e^{-1}/(n-1)!$.

Comment: so a slightly shifted Poisson distribution

Comment: Yes, correct...